# Project Help: Function and Struct issues in C?

Tags: c, function, struct

I'm doing a school project and I'm having a lot of difficult with it.
Currently I'm working on two functions and struct. The first function should randomly generate a line from a file(a movie is stored on each line) and then the second function should  replace all the characters with asterisks like a hangman game. The struct should store the normal film title and the hidden one from each function.

I can't see where I'm going wrong here if anyone could see an error? The program compiles okay but when I run the program it does nothing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
            char title[50];
            char hidden[50];
        }Title;

void Film(Title t){

FILE *fopen(), *fp;

    fp = fopen("Film.txt", "r");
    int i=0;
    int number;
    char movies[44][50];

    while( i<45 ){

        fgets(movies[i], sizeof(movies[i]), fp);
        i++;

    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    number = (rand() % 44);

    //strcpy(t.title[50], movies[number]);
    movies[number] == t.title[50];


    printf("%s", t.title);
    return;
    fclose(fp);
    }

char Star(Title t){

    int val;
    char c;
    int lenMovie;

    printf("%s", t.title);
    lenMovie = strlen(t.title);
    //strcpy(t.hidden, t.title[50]);
    t.title[50] == t.hidden[50];

    for(val=0; val <= lenMovie; val++)
    {

        c = t.hidden[val]; 



        if(c >= 'a' && c<= 'z'){


            printf("*");
            t.hidden[val] = '*';
        }

        else if(c >= 'A' && c<= 'Z'){

            printf("*");
            t.hidden[val] = '*';
        }
        else{

            printf("%c", c);
            t.hidden[val] = c;
        }




}

    printf("%s", t.hidden);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
Title t;

    Film (t);
    Star (t);

    }
```

Comment: Run it step by step using a debugger and see what happens.

Comment: Format your code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleanup of most of the screwups:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    char title[50];
    char hidden[50];
}Title;

void Film(Title* pT)
{
    int i=0;
    int number;
    char movies[44][50];

    FILE *fp = NULL;
    fp = fopen("Film.txt", "r");

    for(i=0; i<44; ++i)
    {
        fgets(movies[i], sizeof(movies[i]), fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    number = (rand() % 44);
    strcpy(pT->title, movies[number]);

    printf("%s", pT->title);
}

char Star(Title* pT)
{
    int val;
    char c;
    int lenMovie;

    printf("%s", pT->title);
    lenMovie = strlen(t->title);
    strcpy(pT->hidden, pT->title]);

    for(val=0; val <= lenMovie; val++)
    {
        c = t.hidden[val]; 

        if(c >= 'a' && c<= 'z')
        {
            printf("*");
            pT->hidden[val] = '*';
        }
        else if(c >= 'A' && c<= 'Z')
        {
            printf("*");
            pT->hidden[val] = '*';
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", c);
            pT->hidden[val] = c;
        }
    }

    printf("%s", pT->hidden);
}

int main(){
    Title t;

    srand(time(NULL));

    Film (&t);
    Star (&t);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the '==' back to '='! I was changing a lot when I was trying to get it working and that was something I must have forgotten to change back -.-" Again, I realise that it's wrong and sorry ><

In regards to the file part, that's what I've been told to use and it hasn't caused any issues in the past so I apologise for that.

Comment: Changing '==' back to '!=' in `t.title[50] == t.hidden[50]` doesn't change anything. It's just as stupid.

Comment: While it is possible that re-declaring fopen won't cause any problems, it also doesn't make any sense.  If you keep your code small, it is easier to read and debug.  Don't put non-sensical statements in code.

Comment: I know that, it was another thing I've already failed at, I'm desperate to get this code working. If you could suggest a better alternative it would be far more helpful.

Comment: It's working great now, thank you so much! I've been stuck on this for too long!I never would have used pointers but now I see why I should have! Thanks :D!!

Answer (score 1):

In C, structs are passed by value, so `Film(t)` and `Star(t)` each operate on their own independent **copy** of `t`. The struct `t` that is being copied is uninitialized, so when `Star()` goes to read from its fields you may see strange behavior.

You could have these functions take a pointer to struct (a `Title *`), and pass the address of `t` to both functions. I didn't fully examine the code so this may not be a comprehensive assessment of the issues in the code.

Comment: Thanks but I was never properly shown how to use pointers to I tend to avoid them whenever possible!